Freeipa groups showing long propagation delay to client
When I create a group and group membership  on the FreeIPA server, user membership does not immediately become visible on the client. Re-booting the client fixes this. Logging out of the user (test678) who is newly a group member and logging in again, doesn't.
Is there anything I can do to "push" or even "pull" the new group membership to the clients, short of completely rebooting them? I have tried purging the sss cache # sss_cache -U and sss_cache -G while the user is logged out, but this had no effect.
Also is this a bug, or expected behaviour?
Details: On IPA server,
# ipa group-add test4
# ipa group-add-member --users=test678

On client, after logging out of test678 and logging in again
$ groups
test678

log out, execute sss_cache -U; sss_cache -G as root, log in test678, same again
reboot, log in as test678,
$ groups
test678 test4

Freeipa is ipa-server-4.10.2-4.el9_3.1.x86_64 running on Rocky 9.3. The client is running Fedora 40, freeipa-client-4.12.1-1.fc40.x86_64
